# Django / app import problem from submodule

Tags: django, django-settings, django-import-export

I'm writing my own Django app, and trying to import submodule from my core library like that:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'core.login',
]
```

And interpreter gives me:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
Cannot import 'login'.
Check that 'core.login.apps.CustomloginConfig.name' is correct.
```

So `login.apps` looks like that

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomloginConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'login'
```

Are there any rules how I can edit this files to start Django properly?

Comment: just take ```'login'``` only instead of ```'core.login'``` in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

apps.py file needs to be as so

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomloginConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'core.login'
```

This is where you tell django that I have registered this app 'core.login' and where to find it.

If login folder is in a core folder, then the above should work.

I think theres a lot of django apps out there that have organized things this way.
One being Kiwi but Im sure theres many others.